# How to filter list of dictionaries with another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django

I want to filter through list of dictionaries with another list of dictionaries in Python and Django.

I have a list of filters as follows:

```
filters = [{'type': 'make', 'value': 'SEAT'}, {'type': 'model', 'value': 'Acura'}]
```

And I have a list of vehicles as follows:

```
vehicles = [
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A3', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A1', 'transmission': 'Automatic'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'Acura', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'LEON', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Skoda', 'model': 'Octavia', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
]
```

I want to get all vehicles with `make Seat` and `model Acura`. Thus the result that I want is:

```
[      
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'Acura', 'transmission': 'Manual'}
]
```

I tried something as follows:

```
def filter_item(vehicle, filters):
    for fil in filters:
        key = fil['type']
        value = fil['value']
        if key == 'make':
            if vehicle.make == value:
                continue
        elif key == 'model':
            if vehicle.model == value:
                continue
        else:
            return False

    return True

vehicles = list(filter(lambda vehicle: filter_item(vehicle, filters), vehicles))
```

But that gives me all vehicles.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Thus, if I have filters as follows:

```
filters = [
   {'type': 'make', 'value': 'SEAT'},
   {'type': 'model', 'value': 'Acura'},
   {'type': 'model', 'value': 'LEON'}
]
```

I want next result:

```
[      
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'Acura', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'LEON', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
]
```

How can I do that?

Do I need to change the structure of the `filters` list or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your filtering does not return `False` given the `vehicle.make` is not the same as `value`, etc.

You can rewrite the filter to:

```
def filter_item(vehicle, filters):
    for fil in filters:
        key = fil['type']
        value = fil['value']
        if key == 'make':
            if vehicle.make != value:
                return False
        elif key == 'model':
            if vehicle.model != value:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

or we can make use of `getattr`:

```
def filter_item(vehicle, filters):
    for fil in filters:
        if fil['value'] != getattr(vehicle, fil['type']):
            return False
    return True
```

or with an [**`all(..)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
def filter_item(vehicle, filters):
    return all(fil['value'] == getattr(vehicle, fil['type']) for fil in filters)
```

If you aim to filter Django records, I however strongly advice to filter as much (as possible) on the database, since a database is optimized for this task.

**EDIT**: you can make a conjuction of disjunctions of the same field. For example by pre-processing the filters:

```
from collections import defaultdict

filter_dict = defaultdict(set)
for fil in filters:
    filter_dict[fil['type']].add(fil['value'])

def filter_item(vehicle):
    return all(getattr(vehicle, k) in v for k, v in filter_dict.items())
```

If your `vehicle` is not an object with attributes, but a dictionary, you should replace `getattr(vehicle, k)` to `vehicle[k]`.

Comment: What if i have two models in filters? As follows `filters = [
  {'type': 'make', 'value': 'Seat'},
  {'type': 'model', 'value': 'Acura'},
  {'type': 'model', 'value': 'LEON'}
]`

Comment: @Boky: then that will not provide any value, since the make can not be both `Seat` and `Acura`. If you want to filter models, I however strongly advice to do the filtering at the database level.

Comment: Am going to change my question than, because that is what I want.

Comment: Super. One more question. What if I have `min_price` and `max_price` in filters, and I want to compare if the price in the vehicle is between `min_price` and `max_price` ?

Comment: @Boky: I would inspect the list of filters, exclude this, and then do an extra filtering on the price.

Answer (score 2):

```py
vehicles = [
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A3', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A1', 'transmission': 'Automatic'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'Acura', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'LEON', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Skoda', 'model': 'Octavia', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
]


filters = [
   {'type': 'make', 'value': 'Seat'},
   {'type': 'model', 'value': 'Acura'},
   {'type': 'model', 'value': 'LEON'}
]


filters_ = dict.fromkeys(vehicles[0].keys(), tuple())

for filt in filters:
    filters_[filt['type']] += (filt['value'],) 

[vehicle for vehicle in vehicles 
 if all((vehicle[key] in val or not val) for key, val in filters_.items())]


Out[17]: 
[{'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'Acura', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
 {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'LEON', 'transmission': 'Manual'}]
```